# Webpack dll reference plugin giving run time error

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, dllplugin, dllreferenceplugin

I am using `webpack` `DllReference` plugin to refer my `node_modules` and `polyfills` from my `webpack.config` so that I don't have to compile them everytime I build my project. The plugin is compiling correctly and creating `js` and `Json` files as it should but when I want to run the project it gives me `function expected` js error in my main.js, however if I don't use the plugin it runs perfectly fine.

I have used following link to study how dll reference plugin works https://medium.com/@emilycoco/how-to-use-the-dll-plugin-to-speed-up-your-webpack-build-dbf330d3b13c